# Multiplying quantities by scalars in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: units, conversion, version-11.3

I'm no longer able to multiply scalars by quantities in Mathematica 11.3. In previous versions the code

```
3*Quantity[1, "mm"]
```

evaluated to

> ```
> 3 mm
> ```

Now it returns

> ```
> 3(1 mm)
> ```

which throws errors in subsequent calculations.

Multiplying quantities by other quantities still works fine.

Assuming this change is not a bug, but intentional, how am I supposed to multiply quantities and scalars in 11.3?

Answer (score 3):

It works on my Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10 as you expect, i.e. returns

```
3 mm
```

Try restarting the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the behavior like this just yesterday after recently installing *Mathematica* on that machine. The `Duration` function applied to an `Audio` returned a form, IIRC `` SomeContext`Quantity[SomeContext`UndefinedQuantity[3.141`, "s"]] ``; I do not remember what the context was. I did not pay much attention to that, as I got the result I wanted, albeit in a weird form; some time after, when I evaluated another expression involving a quantity, I saw a `PrintTemporary`-generated output cell with a message to the effect "Downloading from Wolfram server (*xx*%)" with the progress value *xx* ticking from 0 to 100, and quantities magically began working. I think you are hitting a bug.

Please try to figure out what would trigger the download of the missing package, and file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, just a comment.

I am experiencing a similar issue but I have noticed it when dealing with time quantities. I have to quit Mathematica to restore the normal behavior. I don't know what triggers it but I have a small notebook on my second monitor with this dynamic expression which I'm hoping will help me figure this out:

```
Dynamic[If[(-Quantity[1, "Minutes"]) + Quantity[1, "Hours"] == Quantity[59, "Minutes"],
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> LightGreen]; "OK",
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> Red]; "NOK"], 
 UpdateInterval -> 2]
```

Comment: Mine is also about time (see my non-answer). Did you see the download progress as I did, or any of there unevaluated form returned instead of time? Just wondering if we can narrow it down to the level of reproducibility suitable to open a bug case. I, for one, am unable to repro the issue.

Comment: During my regular workflow, I rarely see the downloading from wolfram messages. However I use the network functions a lot (HTTPRequest and friends).

Comment: I seen these download progress messages while pulling example data, e. g. `ExampleData[{"Audio", "Bird"}]`. The datum is cached then, so it occurs only once per datum. The quantity somehow caused a very similar behavior, apparently pulling a paclet. And my quantity was the most regular temporal seconds, nothing non-trivial. No idea if quantities displayed at all before that; MMA had been installed on that machine afresh just for a couple hours. So you did not see that, but a full restart of the whole rig helped. Looks like quantities break in different ways to different people. :(